# Single Page Application in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to implement single page application in angular.js

I found one demo

http://scotch.io/demos/angular-single-page-routing

which is fine

But i notice 
http://scotch.io/demos/angular-single-page-routing#/contact

There is # tag in it  for each url

Can we make it like 
http://scotch.io/demos/angular-single-page-routing/a/contact

Here a may be play role of #

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: use html5 mode anabled

Comment: How. i have no idea ? Could you please explain ?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-and-html5-modes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As New Dev pointed out through the Docs link, there are two ways to do routing in Angular for single page application.

One way involves the hashbangs, it is more portable across browsers and also allows you to bookmark an entry. The other method is to use the HTML5 Mode which will manipulate the history object directly. It needs Angular to be active on the page, thus you cannot bookmark it. That's the method you are asking for.

To implement it, you would $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

This is lifted directly from Angular the docs linked by New Dev in his comment (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-and-html5-modes).

```js
function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change something in the ul class, however there is no problem with your code, except the href navigation is added to your code  determined using # , change the following href in your class nav navbar-nav navbar-right about.html | contact.html , delete the hash # in your href. You dnt need to shift pages to a new distenation , but if you want move the page contact.html for example to a newfolder called (a) then go back to your source code implement the href to a/contact.html